# Compressing image before sending to SageMaker TF Serving

Tags: python-3.x, rest, tensorflow-serving, image-compression, amazon-sagemaker

I'm able to successfully send batches of images as a numpy array to my SageMaker endpoint set up using TF serving and get a response, like this:.

```
def predict_random_batch(self, batch_size, verbose=0, initial_args=None): 
    batch = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(batch_size,self.size,self.size,3))
    data = {'instances': np.asarray(batch).astype(self.dtype)}
    if verbose: self.total_size(data)
    request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args)
    response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    probs = self._handle_response(response)['predictions']
    return probs

predictor.predict_random_batch(3)
```

However, the numpy array is very big. I'm trying to compress the image batches before sending. This is what I'm attempting:

```
def predict_random_batch_TEST(self, batch_size, verbose=0, initial_args=None): 
    import base64
    batch = np.random.uniform(low=-1.0, high=1.0, size=(batch_size,self.size,self.size,3))
    batch = batch.astype(self.dtype)
    encoded_input_string = base64.b64encode(batch)
    input_string = encoded_input_string.decode("utf-8")
    instance = [{"b64": input_string}]
    data = json.dumps({"instances": instance})        
    request_args = self._create_request_args(data, initial_args)
    if verbose: self.total_size(data)
    response = self.sagemaker_session.sagemaker_runtime_client.invoke_endpoint(**request_args)
    probs = self._handle_response(response)['predictions']
    return probs
```

However this returns the error:

> ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the
>   InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (400) from model with
>   message "{ "error": "JSON Value: . . .  Is not object" }"

Does anybody know how I can compress a batch of images to be able to send a larger batch size? Apparently SM imposes a 5MB payload limit which is not very big when sending as a numpy array.

Answer (score 2):

I use a separate API to resize images before sending them to an endpoint. Here's the code snippet, you should have no problem adapting it.

```
h = body['height']
w = body['width']
image = base64.b64decode(body['data'])
L = len(image)

image = np.fromstring(image, np.uint8)
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
(H, W, _) = image.shape
image = cv2.resize(image, (h, w,))
image = cv2.imencode('.jpeg', image)
data = base64.b64encode(image[1].tostring())
```

Full post here: https://medium.com/@julsimon/using-chalice-to-serve-sagemaker-predictions-a2015c02b033

Comment: Can't seem to get this to work. Do I need to modify my saved model or Tensorflow serving in order for it to accept json serialized jpeg byte strings instead of json serialized Numpy arrays?

Comment: I'd say no. It feels simpler to feed your model whatever it expects, so I'd just resize the image with the cv2 code above and then serialize the numpy array.

Comment: My issue is the serialized Numpy Array doesn’t seem effficient and I’m running into a 5MB max payload size with fairly small images

Comment: If you want large batch sizes and aren't don't need real-time request/response behavior, maybe [SageMaker Batch Transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-batch.html) would be a better fit?